# "pip install requirements.txt" command returns many errors, including 404 not found

Tags: python3, django

```
(myenv1) root@p-VirtualBox:~/online-exam/onlineexam# pip install requirements.txt 
Collecting requirements.txt
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/online-exam/myenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/root/online-exam/myenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/root/online-exam/myenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/root/online-exam/myenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/root/online-exam/myenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/root/online-exam/myenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/root/online-exam/myenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/root/online-exam/myenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/root/online-exam/myenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/root/online-exam/myenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/root/online-exam/myenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/root/online-exam/myenv1/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/requirements-txt/
```

Comment: Hello Pushkar, you should include the contents of requirements.txt and also explain what you are trying to accomplish, having background information is always helpful. The error seems to be a mistake in the requirements file.

Comment: pip does not play well with apt(it can screw up your install).  if you need to install a program with pip, you should use pipx

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Typo mistake may be, you are missing `-r` so try `pip install -r requirements.txt` . That's it tried to get `requirements-txt` from remote store.

Comment: @TrailRider , It is ok for this case, he is using a virtual-env, see `(myenv1)` at  top corner.

Answer (score 14):

You are missing `-r` command flag, so go again with:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

As it was before, `pip` just try to get `requirements-txt` from remote store expecting it to be a package name.

See `pip help install`

> **Usage:**
>
> ```
>   pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
>   pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
>
> ...
>   pip also supports installing from "requirements files", which provide
>   an easy way to specify a whole environment to be installed.
> ```
>
> **Install Options:**
>
> ```
>   -r, --requirement <file>    Install from the given requirements file. This option
>                               can be used multiple times.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

or

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

would help